# How to handle several submits when they are not part of a form

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, submit, form-submit

For reading values of multiple checkboxes with several submit options, i use this code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
   <input type="submit" name="move" value="Move"/>
   <input type="submit" name="copy" value="Copy"/>

</form>
```

Each submit should do a different action and my php looks like this:

```
if($_POST['delete']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        // code for delete goes here
        echo 'Files are  deleted!';
    }
  }
}

if($_POST['move']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        //code for moving files goes here
        echo 'Files are moved!';
    }
  }
}

if($_POST['copy']) {
  if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
        // code for copy goes here
        echo 'Files are copied!';
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for me.
What i want to achieve: I want to put the submits on a complete different place on the website. 
Something like below:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
</form>

<!-- some code goes here -->

<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
<input type="submit" name="move" value="Move"/>
<input type="submit" name="copy" value="Copy"/>
```

How can i make this work?

By the way: i am using ajax for the post action

Comment: change type="submit" to type="button" give id to each button , on click event you can serilize  form data and post through ajax

Comment: can you give a little piece of example code? I mean, for the click event and serializing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the submit to button

```
<input type="button" class="submit-form" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
<input type="button" class="submit-form" name="move" value="Move"/>
<input type="button" class="submit-form" name="copy" value="Copy"/>
```

and need to add id to form

```
<form action="url/goeshere" id="my-form" method="post">
```

Your ajax form submit will be some thing like this

```
$(".submit-form").click(function(event) {
  $form = $("#my-form");
  $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize() + "&submit="+ 
  $(this).attr("value"), function(data) {
    // do something with response (data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use some jquery for this case :

```
  <script>
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
     var _form = $("form");
    _form.append($("<input/>",{"name":$(this).attr("name")}));
    _form.submit();
   });
 </script>
```